# Read file from position (to position)

Tags: c++, file

File-Stream/ifstreamreadbufferandseekfileposition.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0240_File-Stream/ifstreamreadbufferandseekfileposition.htm

this page is able to print content of a file twice using

```
file.seekg(0);
```

So I assume that seekg(0) puts the "cursor" (in java) to the beginning of the file, and this web site: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ confirms me.

But when I do this to a file that contains (0\n0\n0\n):

```
while(getline(file,line)) {
    CCLOG(line.c_str());
    CCLOG("%d",(int)file.tellg());
}

file.seekg(0);
CCLOG("%d",(int)file.tellg());

while(getline(file,line)) {
    CCLOG(line.c_str());
}
```

(I'm doing this in cocos2dx 2.2.2 by the way)

it prints:

```
0
2
0
4
0
6
-1
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour you are seeing is that, once you read to the end of the file, the eof() state flag will be set. Any attempt to read or position the file after that will trigger an error. The error resulting in a return code of ERROR, which is -1.

You can reset the state flags (all of them) using clear(). So the code should read

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here (and what it has to do with Java), but if you're asking why resetting the file cursor to the beginning of the file does not work, then here's my answer:

Make sure you reset the error flags of file before you call `seekg`. So instead of just

```
file.seekg(0);
```

write

```
file.clear();
file.seekg(0);
```

That will successfully reset the file cursor to the beginning of the file. The reason for this is, that once you reach the end of the file, the EOF (end-of-file) flag will be set and `seekg` does not reset it.